# ionic 5 modal sometimes does not show image

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

My modal opens and should show a previously selected image. **My problem is that only the first time I open it brings up the image** The images exist, I analyze them on the console and I see them if I browse them. There is no error here.

The case of upper and lower case I have reviewed it.
the problem is with images, not with text information, the information is perfect.
For some reason, it stops emitting ionImgDidLoad and ionImgWillLoad.

I will appreciate if you can help me, I can not see the error, thank you very much!

**ts:**

```
import { ModalExamplePage } from '../modal-Example/modal-Example.page';
…
public info_to_modal = {};
…..
this.info_to_modal = {
   photo: this.img_1,
   name: this.name
}
```

**I call the modal like this inside an async function:**

```
const modal = await this.modalController.create({
   component: ModalExamplePage,
   cssClass: 'my-custom-modal-info',
   componentProps: {
      datainfo: this.info_to_modal
   },
});
return await modal.present();
```

**in modal (ts):**

```
@Input() public datainfo;
```

**Then in the html:**

```
<ion-thumbnail slot="start">
   <ion-img [src]="datainfo.photo"></ion-img>
</ion-thumbnail>
```